"From one who is no longer of this world." from The Chocolate Box
In one of the short stories of Hercule Poirot, The Chocolate Box, there was the following dialog between Madame Déroulard and the detective.

"Monsieur Poirot," said the old lady, "I have just learned that you are not what you pretend to be. You are a police officer."
"That is so, madame."
"You came here to inquire into the circumstances of my son's death?"
Again I replied: "That is so, madame."
"I should be glad if you would tell me what progress you have made."
I hesitated.
"First I would like to know how you have learned all this, madame."
"From one who is no longer of this world."
Christie, Agatha. "The Chocolate Box." 1923. Poirot Investigates. 1925. New Bantam Edition. New York: Bantam, 1970, 6th printing 1978. pp. 184–198. Quote is from p. 195. Accessed at archive.org 27 December 2024.

Hercule Poirot was introduced (by Virginie Mesnard) to the household as a journalist. But it looks there was nobody dead from when the detective was presented to the house, to when the above dialog took place.
The only person who was murdered was the old lady's son, Paul Déroulard, and Paul was dead even before Hercule Poirot arrived at his house. So there was no way Paul could tell his mom the real identity of the detective.
That's why I am bewildered at who the old Madame Déroulard was referring to by "one who is no longer of this world".

Madame Déroulard is referring not to her son Paul, but to Virginie. As you note, it was Virginie who had tearfully asked Poirot to look into Paul's death and introduced him into the household. The servant François claims that both Mme Déroulard and Virginie are very religious, but Poirot has his doubts about the latter:

"The women are all devout—a good thing perhaps. Madame est très pieuse—et Mademoiselle Virginie aussi."
Mademoiselle Virginie? Was she "très pieuse"? Thinking of the tear-stained passionate face I had seen that first day, I wondered.
p. 194.

In other words, Poirot knows that Virginie had been in love with Paul and so he doubts her piety. But we find out that François is right about Virginie's religious nature, because in the conversation Mme Déroulard has with Poirot, she mentions in passing that Virginie has become a nun:

"It is well that I sent for you. It is the providence of the good God that Virginie told me before she departed for the convent, what she had done."
p. 195, emphasis added.

Since Virginie is now a nun, she has renounced the world. This explains Mme Déroulard's somewhat dramatic description of her as "one who is no longer of this world."

Ah, my misunderstanding. Thanks for the quick answer. It makes perfect sense now.
